# SQL compute a column from two rows

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I'm looking to compute a column based on two other columns, but I have some special cases where the computation has to take multiple rows into account.

Here's the query as it stands now:

```
SELECT
    UserName
    , EntryDate
    , Project
    , HoursWorked
    , HoursAvailable
    , UtilPct as HoursWorked / HoursAvailable
FROM
    MyDatabase
ORDER BY
    EntryDate
```

Which results in:

`UserName EntryDate  Project HoursWorked HoursAvailable UtilPct

Justin    12/17/2012 ABC     8         8            100

Justin    12/18/2012 ABC     4         8            50

Justin    12/18/2012 DEF     4         8            50`

But 50% utilization for the last two entries is wrong, because both happened on the same day. Both of those rows should show 100%.

I need the query to...

1. Sum up all of the HoursWorked for a certain day
2. Divide that by the max HoursAvailable for that day
3. Put that value into the UtilPct column for each row

How do I make it do that?

Comment: sum up for each user separate?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. And yes, the utilization should be summed up per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the query to...
>
> Sum up all of the HoursWorked for a certain day
>      Divide that by the max HoursAvailable for that day
>      Put that value into the UtilPct column for each row
>
> How do I make it do that?

Sum up all of the HoursWorked:

```
SUM(HoursWorked) ... GROUP BY EntryDate
```

Divide that by the max HoursAvailable for that day

```
SUM(HoursWorked)/MAX(HoursAvailable) ... GROUP BY EntryDate
```

Put that value into the UtilPct column for each row:

```
SELECT ... SUM(HoursWorked)/MAX(HoursAvailable)*100.0 AS UtilPct
    FROM MyDatabase
    GROUP BY EntryDate
    ORDER BY EntryDate
```

But now you won't be able to divide the rows by `Project`, you will only see the time utilization any single day. If you try to `GROUP BY` `Project`, you will get 50% instead of 100% again.

That is because you are asking for 4/8 to be 100%, and that would get you semantically nonsensical answers, such as "On Tuesday, I worked 100% on project ABC, *and also* 100% on project DEF", to which one could answer "So on Tuesdays there's 200% of you?"

You can solve the quandary using a `JOIN` between the table and itself to get the `TotalHoursWorked` *in a single day*, which is semantically different from the HoursWorked *on a single project*:

```
SELECT
    UserName
    , md1.EntryDate
    , Project
    , HoursWorked
    , HoursAvailable
    , (TotalHoursWorked / HoursAvailable)*100.0 AS UtilPct
FROM
    MyDatabase AS md1
    JOIN ( 
        SELECT EntryDate, SUM(HoursWorked) AS TotalHoursWorked
        FROM MyDatabase GROUP BY EntryDate
    ) AS md2 ON (md1.EntryDate = md2.EntryDate)
ORDER BY
    md1.EntryDate
```

Now the UtilPct will refer to the time usage of that day, which means you could get a 100% value on a project even if you worked at it for five minutes only, provided those five minutes were all that you had available that day. And you will still be able to add another column to indicate the percentage of `HoursWorked` over `HoursAvailable` for that *project* that *day* (in most systems, it ought to be roughly proportional to that project's priority).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that you took the time to explain each part of your answer. Very helpful. I took some ideas from some of the other answers, but your answer was the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.Username, 
    a.EntryDate,
    a.Project,
    a.HoursWorked,
    (b.TotalHoursWorked / a.HoursAvailable) * 100 as 'UtilPct'
FROM
    MyDatabase a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
       SUM(HoursWorked) as TotalHoursWorked, 
       Username, 
       EntryDate 
     FROM 
       MyDatabase 
     GROUP BY 
       Username, EntryDate) b
ON
  a.Username = b.Username
  AND a.EntryDate = b.EntryDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2475f/5)**

```
SELECT
      t.UserName
    , t.EntryDate
    , t.Project
    , t.HoursWorked
    , t.HoursAvailable
    , (SELECT SUM(HoursWorked) 
      FROM MyDatabase 
      WHERE MyDatabase.EntryDate =t.EntryDate)/
      (SELECT MAX(HoursAvailable) 
      FROM MyDatabase 
      WHERE MyDatabase.EntryDate =t.EntryDate) AS UtilPct
FROM
    MyDatabase t
ORDER BY
    t.EntryDate
```

Result:

```
| USERNAME |                       ENTRYDATE | PROJECT | HOURSWORKED | HOURSAVAILABLE | UTILPCT |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Justin | December, 17 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     ABC |           8 |              8 |       1 |
|   Justin | December, 18 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     ABC |           4 |              8 |       1 |
|   Justin | December, 18 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     DEF |           4 |              8 |       1 |
```

By the way nice name in table.

Answer (score 0):

The sub query just sums up the day.

```
        SELECT
              t.UserName
            , t.EntryDate
            , t.Project
            , t.HoursWorked
            , t.HoursAvailable
            , CASE WHEN HoursAvailable = 0 THEN 0 
                   ELSE Round(HoursWorked / HoursAvailable * 100.0, 2) 
                   END AS UtilPct
        FROM
            MyTable t
            INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT EntryDate,
                      UserName,          
                      SUM(HoursWorked) AS HoursWorked,
                      MAX(HoursAvailable) AS HoursAvailable
              FROM MyTable
              GROUP BY EntryDate,
                       UserName) AS Daily
        ON t.EntryDate = Daily.EntryDate
           AND t.UserName = Daily.UserName
        ORDER BY
            t.EntryDate,
            t.UserName
```